# Javascript removing a class from a list of elements only deletes half of the elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, visualization

I am currently working on a Word Puzzle algorithm that takes in a set of words and displays them on a grid. The user can then solve the puzzle himself or he can click a button called solve. This will call a function that visually solves the Word Puzzle. And this is where I am stuck:
The solving algorithm traverses the grid for each word and if there is a match with the first letter of the searched word, the algorithm proceeds to search the nearby characters of the matched field. Each field the is traversed that way gets a class that colors the background. This way, you can see which fields are searched right now.

Here is a demonstration:
https://www.loom.com/share/b8fa66d2bddf4b4a9382bdf13e6aa2f3

After beeing finished with a word the found word should be colored in green, all the other classes should be removed. This should be achieved using a function that gets all the elements of a certain class and then removes this class from those elements. The function also gets called whenever the user clicks on "clear gird".

This is what the function looks like:

```
function resetColor(classname) {
    let points = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);

    for (const point of points) {
      console.log(points, classname);
      point.classList.remove(classname);
    }
  }
```

However, whenever the function gets called, it only deletes every second instance of the class.

To demonstrate this, here is a small video showcasing this: https://www.loom.com/share/a48a5b38f4e0449584037c5119dce5fa
(I only called the function to reset all green fields, that's why the pruple fields don't get removed)

For reference, here is my github repository for the complete code:
https://github.com/lamorak13/Word-Puzzle

So my question is: Why does the funciton only delete every second instance of the class?

I am grateful for any help I can get ^^

Comment: Live HTML Collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with a live html collection. When you remove the class, you remove the element from the collection. So when you remove index 0, the index of 1 moves to zero. So you end up removing every other one since every time you remove one, the rest slide down a position.

Typically you loop in the opposite direction or use a while loop

**While loop**

```js
function resetColor(classname) {
  let points = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);

  while (points.length) {
    points[0].classList.remove(classname);
  }

}

resetColor('red')
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="red">1</div>
<div class="red">2</div>
<div class="red">3</div>
<div class="red">4</div>
<div class="red">5</div>
```

**reverse for loop**

```js
function resetColor(classname) {
  let points = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);

  for (let i= points.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    points[i].classList.remove(classname);
  }

}

resetColor('red')
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="red">1</div>
<div class="red">2</div>
<div class="red">3</div>
<div class="red">4</div>
<div class="red">5</div>
```

**Convert it to an array**

```js
function resetColor(classname) {
  let points = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);

  Array.from(points).forEach( function (point) {
    point.classList.remove(classname);
  });
}

resetColor('red')
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="red">1</div>
<div class="red">2</div>
<div class="red">3</div>
<div class="red">4</div>
<div class="red">5</div>
```